# Query Not Working in MYSql QUERY php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this query i am trying to get work but i can't see the problem here. I need to know why this part   `"AND time >= $currentdate"`  not working .

I just want to take something between dates .
    please help me with that Many Thanks.

```
function checkDateForImages(){
    global $mysqli;
    $saturdaydate=strtotime("Saturday");
    $currentdate=strtotime("now");
    $sunday=strtotime("sunday");
    $sunday = strtotime("-1 week", $sunday);
    $saturdaydate=date("Y-m-d", $saturdaydate);
    $currentdate=date("Y-m-d", $currentdate);
    $sunday=date(" Y-m-d", $sunday);
    $storeArray = Array();

    if(!date($currentdate==$saturdaydate)){
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_name_01 FROM `products` WHERE time >= $sunday AND time >= $currentdate ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 3 ");
        while ($col = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $storeArray[] =  $col['image_name_01']; 
        }


    }
return $storeArray;
}
```

Comment: datatype of time?

Comment: what error you are getting.

Comment: Would you show us the structure of the table `products` with the creation script ?

Comment: If you were using prepared statements you would probably not be stuck on this problem now.

Comment: What happens if you try the query direct against the database in PHPMyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

As `time` may be `date` or `datetime` data-type, You have to enclosed value in quotes. Change your query to:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_name_01 FROM `products` WHERE time >= '$sunday' AND time >= '$currentdate' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 3 ");
```

Also remove space before `Y` while you are converting Sunday timestamp to date format.

Change line

```
$sunday=date(" Y-m-d", $sunday);
```

to

```
$sunday=date("Y-m-d", $sunday);
```

Comment: This should be closed (IMHO) as a simple typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
WHERE time >= $sunday AND time >= $currentdate
```

With

```
WHERE time >= $sunday AND time <= $currentdate
```